# Encryption with a caret in it (with key)

Tags: encryption

I am trying to find out what encryption this is.

There seems to be a caret (^) after the first 3 letters

AsE^YHJ751 with the key 1524c1d6bea19a14d3dfef7648e5ce1c

Qpr^45sLz with the key da862dfda878ae936a2bbfc9f812f38f

Very much appreciated

Comment: Questions about cryptography that do not include an implementation problem are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Normally I would recommend posting this at http://crypto.stackexchange.com, however I'm not sure anyone will be interested in a "guess the algorithm" question.

Comment: And even before "guess the algorithm", it looks like you'll have to play "guess the encoding" as well.